# Create a multidimentional array out of two simple arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I know I can create a new array with a double for loops filling it up value by value, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it...

Here's the situation:

I have two arrays:

```
String[] arrayA = {"AA", "AB", "AC"};
String[] arrayB = {"B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"};
```

And I want to create a third one `arrayC` out of them with data like:

```
    AA B1 B2 B3 B4
    AB B1 B2 B3 B4
    AC B1 B2 B3 B4
```

So, The 1st Column is `arrayA`

And every line `i` starting from `arrayC[i][1]` is arrayB

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: There is no simpler way. But you can replace inner loop with `Arrays.copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the `arrayB` elements with System.arraycopy :

```
System.arraycopy(arrayB, // source array
                 0, // starting position in the source array
                 arrayC[i], // destination array
                 1, // starting position in the destination data
                 arrayB.length); // number of elements to copy
```